# vertical divider between two columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap, and have a row which has two columns (span6). How do I create a vertical divider between both the spans.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: I did a version which doesn't require extra elements:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815081/how-can-i-add-a-line-between-two-columns-using-twitter-bootstraps-grid-system/29341777#answer-29341777

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If your code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I'd assume you're using additional DIVS within the "span6" DIVS for holding/styling your content? So...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="mycontent-left">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="mycontent-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you could simply add some CSS to the "mycontent-left" class to create your divider.

```
.mycontent-left {
  border-right: 1px dashed #333;
}
```

Comment: the problem with the above is that it the border sticks to my content in the first span. In the first span I have a form, and the border is hugging its contents. How can I separate it ?

Comment: Simple - add some padding to the content-left and content-right DIVS.

Comment: The problem would happen if the content of the right `<span>` higher than the left one. In that case, the vertical line will be ugly.

Comment: If the columns are of different heights, you can make the line run all the way down by setting `min-height: 100%; height: 100%;` in the CSS for the container `div` and the `div`s containing each column.

Comment: @raul I believe that only works if you are using flexbox. If you are using floats on the `col-*` divs, then this won't work.

Answer (score 60):

In Bootstrap 4 there is the utility class `border-right` which you can use.

So for example you can do:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 border-right"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to make this border take 100% of the height ?

Comment: How do you increase the thickness, on end its too faint

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, border-right is replaced by border-end (for left-to-right (LTR) text). See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities and for more on  RTL see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/

Answer (score 32):

```css
.row.vertical-divider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row.vertical-divider > div[class^="col-"] {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  border-left: 3px solid #F2F7F9;
  border-right: 3px solid #F2F7F9;
}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row vertical-divider" style="margin-top: 30px">
  <div class="col-xs-6">Hi there</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">Hi world<br/>hi world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use '+' selector and you don't need first and last child classes: `.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"] + div[class^="col-"] {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px; 
    border-left: 3px solid #0396D1;
   }`

Comment: This solution is the best

Answer (score 18):

Well here's another option which I've been using for some time now. It works great for me since I mostly need it do visually separate 2 cols. And it's also responsive. Which means that if I have columns next to each other in medium and large screen sizes, then I would use the class `col-md-border`, which would hide the separator on smaller screen sizes.

**css:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-border:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    }
    .col-md-border + .col-md-border {
        border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
        margin-left: -1px;
    }
}
```

In scss you can generate all needed classes probably from this:

**scss:**

```
@media(min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    .col-md-border {
        &:not(:last-child) {
            border-right: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
        }

        & + .col-md-border {
            border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
            margin-left: -1px;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-border"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-border"></div>
</div>
```

**How it works:**

The cols must be inside an element where there are no other cols otherwise the selectors might not work as expected.

`.col-md-border:not(:last-child)` matches all but the **last element before .row close** and adds right border to it.

`.col-md-border + .col-md-border` matches the second div with the same class if these two are next to each other and adds left border and -1px negative margin. Negative margin is why it doesn't matter anymore which column has greater height and the separator will be 1px the same height as the highest column.

It does also have some problems...

1. When you try to be clever/lazy and use `col-XX-X` class together with `hidden-XX`/`visible-XX` classes inside the same row element.
2. When you have a lot of columns and need a pixel perfect thing. Since it moves n-1 column 1px to the left.

... But on the other hand it's responsive, works great for simple html and it's easy to create these classes for all bootstrap screen sizes.

Comment: Does this work for more than one row, e.g. 2x2?

Comment: @luke_mclachlan By just reading the code, I think this will not produce the required effect once elements start to wrap

Answer (score 9):

To fix the ugly look of a divider being too short when the content of one column is taller, add borders to all columns. Give every other column a negative margin to compensate for position differences.

For example, my three column classes:

```
.border-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.borders {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: -1px;
}
.border-left {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 border-right">First</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 borders">Second</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 border-left">Third</div>
```

Make sure you use #ddd if you want the same color as Bootstrap's horizontal dividers.

Comment: I like this solution but it is designed for only three or more columns. What if you only want two? You're middle ".borders" div will not be there to adjust for the margins.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a vertical divider between 2 columns, all you need is add

```
class="col-6 border-left"
```

to one of your column div-s

BUT

In the world of responsive design, you may need to make it disappear sometimes.

The solution is disappearing `<hr>` + disappearing `<div>` + `margin-left: -1px;`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="border-left d-sm-none d-md-block" style="width: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-left: -1px;">
    <hr class="d-sm-block d-md-none">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8z1pag7s/

tested on Bootstrap 4.1

Comment: This is the absolute working solution! Thank you, bro!

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, `border-left` is replaced by `border-start` (for left-to-right (LTR) text). See getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities and for more on RTL see getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl

Answer (score 8):

With **Bootstrap 4** you can use *borders*, avoiding writing other CSS.

> border-left

And if you want space between content and border you can use *padding*. (in this example padding left 4px)

> pl-4

**Example:**

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-6 border-left pl-4">First</div>
      <div class="offset-6 border-left pl-4">Second</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For **Bootstrap 5.0+** is:

`<div class="row">
<div class="offset-6 border-start border-5">First</div>
<div class="offset-6 border-start border-5">Second</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 6):

If you are still seeking for the best solution in 2018, I found the way this works perfectly if you have at least one free pseudo element( ::after or ::before ).

You just have to add class to your row like this: `<div class="row` *vertical-divider* `">`

And add this to your CSS:

```
.row.vertical-divider [class*='col-']:not(:last-child)::after {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

Any row with this class will now have vertical divider between all of the columns it contains...

You can see how this works in [this example.](https://www.bootply.com/qjvYXfWLuN)

Comment: Omit the - in [class*='col-'] (to [class*='col']) for bootstrap 4 compatibility with class "col"

Comment: just a comment "Property is ignored due to the display. With 'display: inline', the width, height, margin-top, margin-bottom, and float properties have no effect.css"

Comment: why have you copied the above answer from 2016?

Answer (score 4):

I have tested it. It works fine.

```
.row.vdivide [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
      background: #e0e0e0;
      width: 1px;
      content: "";
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      min-height: 70px;
    }

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row vdivide">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><h1>One</h1></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><h1>Two</h1></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><h1>Three</h1></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><h1>Four</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works , perfectly as neeeded , also should have explained what you did .

Comment: Absolutely perfect, and fully responsive - even when columns get stacked on smaller screens the border vanishes, as you would want! A great easy solution, thank you! :)

Comment: not working, the right separator is still there, have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/k4uavbtz/

Comment: Works for 3+ columns. When only using two columns, the divider follows the height of the left column. Therefore, if the right column is longer, the border will not be tall enough.

Answer (score 2):

### Must Open in Full Page to See Borders!

Added media width clauses in the CSS so there isn't any nasty borders on the mobile-friendly side of things. Hope this helps! This will resize to the length of the longest column. Tested on .col-md-4 and .col-md-6 and my assumption is it is compatible with the rest. No guarantees though.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/ooxn0vsr)

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cols {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-4:not(:first-child), 
  .col-md-6:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-md-4:not(:last-child),
  .col-md-6:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    .col-md-6
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h1>
    .col-md-4
  </h1>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cols col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a column space, this is an option. Rebalance the columns depending on what you need.

```
<div class="col-1">
    <div class="col-6 vhr">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.vhr{
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap 5 you can use the classes border-start or border-end.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 border-end">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also the borders will not be seen in extra small devices.

Answer (score 1):

As @WalterV answered above, changed for **Bootstrap 5+**:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="offset-6 border-start border-5">First</div>
      <div class="offset-6 border-start border-5">Second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Confirmed in Bootstrap 5.2.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

As of bootstrap v4 you can use this code

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6 span6 border-right">
      dummy content
   </div>
   <div class="col-6 span6">
      right div content
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
<style>
.vl {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Vertical Rule </title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="vl"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will give the result you want using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I did was remove the gutter between the respective spans then drawing a left border for the left span and a right border for the right span in such a way that their borders overlapped just to give a single line. This way the visible line will just be one of borders.

CSS

```
.leftspan
{
padding-right:20px;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row-fluid .rightspan {
margin-left: -0.138297872340425%;
*margin-left: -0.13191489361702%;
padding-left:20px;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row-fluid .rightspan:first-child {
margin-left: -0.11063829787234%;
*margin-left: -0.104255319148938%;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row-fluid" >
      <div class="span8 leftspan" >
      </div>

      <div class="span4 rightspan"  >
      </div>
 </div>
```

Try this it works for me

Comment: That's ugly when the 2 divs do not have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a vertical divider in **Bootstrap 3.3.7** but they're aren't any by default so I wrote a simple one-line div that did the job for me.

See if it works for you.

```
<div style="display: inline;border-right: 1px solid gray; padding:0 5px;"></div>
```

Thank you for reading. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap V5 introduced the `.vr` [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/vertical-rule/) you place on a `<div>` element.
If needed, place it inside an `<li>` element to separate elements inside `<ul>`element.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>
    <div class="h-100 vr"></div>
  </li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Note : `.navbar-nav` class is related to [navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) and sets the css property `list-style` of all children elements to `none` which is required for the wrapping `<li>` element to display the vertical rule (separator) correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this, 100% guaranteed:-

```
vr {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```