# bootstrap 3 vertical line in button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Button group

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span id="prevBtn">06.02.2014</span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
    <span id="nextBtn">08.08.2014</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
    <span id="toDayBtn">Today</span>
</button>
```

How create vertical divider with bootstrap 3?

http://jsfiddle.net/gJH6w/

[image]

Comment: I think the code is clear enough... Don't really need a fiddle, even if it's better.

Comment: You can use this answer, and convert columns to button as you need : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14580505/2454790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My result

```html
<div style="border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0; margin-left: 20px; float: left; height: 34px">
</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <span id="toDayBtn">Today</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 26):

Here is a `.btn-separator` class to fit your needs :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span id="prevBtn">06.02.2014</span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
            <span id="nextBtn">08.08.2014</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </button>

        <span class="btn-separator"></span>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
            <span id="toDayBtn">Today</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.btn-separator:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #ADADAD;
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/gJH6w/3/)

Comment: Change height: 34px; to height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

If you put your other buttons in their own group on a btn-toolbar, then this works pretty well

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">|</div>
```