# Adding borders to span divs in Bootstrap messes up layout

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting with Twitter Bootstrap and have a question about how layout functions in it. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Test</title>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script  src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">a</div>
                <div class="span8">b</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">c</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
div.container
{
    background-color:#aaa;
}
div.span4, div.span8, div.span12
{
    background-color:#eee;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

Adding border to span4 and span8 increases their width and I end up with this:

[image: bootstrap span layout]

span4 and span8 get stacked while they should be on the same line. I realize I could decrease their width in my .css file and correct this, or use this:

http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

but does Bootstrap provide means to correct this (not adding extra CSS every time I add or remove border, etc)

Comment: (maybe OT, apologies) should this even be tagged CSS?  It seems that you aren't looking for a CSS solution, just a Bootstrap solution.

Comment: I can remove it if it is a problem, I am a new user here and don't have much experience in tagging.

Comment: It does seem to be confusing people :D I was ready to write a CSS answer myself as well.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11299089/1478467

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The span classes in bootstrap have specific widths so adding a border throws off the total for the row and forces them to wrap. To get around this I usually put the border styling on a div inside the div with the span class.  Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">
       <div>a</div>
   </div>
   <div class="span8">
       <div>b</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span4 > div, .span8 > div
{
   background-color:#eee;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   border-radius:3px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: In general, I would try to avoid adding your own styles to the grid classes in bootstrap to avoid conflicts with the grid system.

Comment: What if you want to add a border to a `row` and then nest `span`s inside it?

Comment: Ahah, thanks. This seems like a good solution, although it does add a bit to divitis.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue and playing with the box-sizing didn't help at all. The only solution that worked for me in the end was to use [`row-fluid`](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

The difference with row-fluid is that they are based on percentages, not fixed pixels. Then the child spans in a row always add up to 12, instead of adding up to their parent span width in the normal pixel width rows.

So for example yours would now be

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">a</div>
        <div class="span8">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you don't get any issues with changing margins, paddings, or borders.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your divs to stay on the same line, yes? To do that you'll have to specify a width and float them. Divs tend to always want to stack on top of each other.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/me73v/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I realize I could use CSS to adjust the width of the divs. I was just wondering if Bootstrap itself provided a way to  correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to tweak the span widths with JQuery:

```
$(".some-bordered-container [class*=span] ").each(function(index) {
    $(this).width($(this).width()-1);
});
```

It seems to work well for me. I don't miss the pixels.

Comment: No idea why people are downvoting this. Some people may prefer a jQuery solution. Even though it is not the best approach and CSS should be used when possible, this solution may suit some people better depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use negative margins :

```
div.span4, div.span8, div.span12
{
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: -1px;
}
```

It's not as good a solution as using `box-sizing: border-box`, IMHO, but it's just worth noticing it works, if you're forced to use `box-sizing: content-box`.