# Responsive 2 span6 can't side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Bootstrap Responsive 2 span6 inside span12 not side by side. Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/6TaQt/24/

```
<div class="MainDiv container-fluid" style="border:1px solid pink">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" style="border:1px solid green">    
    <div class="span6" style="border:1px solid red">Span A</div>
    <div class="span6" style="border:1px solid red">Span B</div>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Question makes no sense, you have span 6 nested inside span 12 so what did you expect?

Comment: The layout you are using is not correct (each span nesting requires a row), but the border is the source of the problem : check http://stackoverflow.com/q/11299089/1478467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

........***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/6TaQt/28/)***................

Hi now used to `display:inline-block;`

as like this

```
[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"]{
display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;  
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/6TaQt/28/)***

Comment: That mean I have to include Grid system from bootstrap together with bootstrap-responsive.css?

Answer (score 0):

use float: left for both of the span6 classes

like : style="border:1px solid red; float:left"